# Get Rstudio.exe directory within Rstudio

Tags: powershell, directory, rstudio, pandoc

I want to run pandoc from a command within a script, however, as this script is run on multiple machines where the directory "C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc" may differ, I want to make this variable instead of hardcoded.

I'm looking for a way to automatically find the "C:/Program Files/RStudio" or "C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc" folder within a script. Does someone have a workaround for this?

Any help is appreciated!

Michael

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about a powershell script? otherwise feel free to change the tags again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually an environment variable set within RStudio that has exactly what you're looking for:

```
> Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_PANDOC")
[1] "C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc"
```